CMake and AUTOGEN not working with certain project structure
I have an interesting problem with a CMake project that uses QT and the AUTOGEN approach (AUTOMOC and AUTOUIC in my case).
I have this minimal sample structure:
MinimalCMakeProject/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src/
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── libA/
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include/
│   │   │   └── libA/
│   │   │       ├── bla/
│   │   │       │   └── file1.h
│   │   │       └── blubb/
│   │   │           └── file2.h
│   │   └── src/
│   │       ├── bla/
│   │       │   └── file1.cpp
│   │       └── blubb/
│   │           └── file2.cpp
│   └── libB/
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── include/
│       │   └── libB/
│       │       └── file3.h
│       └── src/
│           └── file3.cpp

LibB depends on libA. All files need to be handled by AUTOMOC and AUTOUIC. If I use target_sources in libA's topmost CMakeLists.txt like this
target_sources(libA
   PRIVATE
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/bla/file1.cpp
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/blubb/file2.cpp
   PUBLIC
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libA/bla/file1.h
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/libA/blubb/file2.h
)

everything works fine.
But now I have e real-life project where libA contains ~30 subfolders like bla and blubb, each containing up to 50 source files. I dont want to pollute libA's CMakeLists.txt with the target_sources definition containing everything. So I added separate CMakeLists.txt like this:
MinimalCMakeProject/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src/
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── libA/
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── include/
│   │   │   └── libA/
│   │   │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │       ├── bla/
│   │   │       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │       │   └── file1.h
│   │   │       └── blubb/
│   │   │           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   │           └── file2.h
│   │   └── src/
│   │       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │       ├── bla/
│   │       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │       │   └── file1.cpp
│   │       └── blubb/
│   │           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │           └── file2.cpp
│   └── libB/
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── include/
│       │   └── libB/
│       │       └── file3.h
│       └── src/
│           └── file3.cpp

In libA's CMakeLists.txt I replaced the target_sources with
add_subdirectory(include/libA)
add_subdirectory(src)

The CMakeLists.txt of include/libAand src use add_subdirectory() with all the subfolders. The file include/libA/bla/CMakeLists.txt has this content:
target_sources(libA
   PUBLIC
      file1.h
)

and similar for all other files.
Now the project compiles nearly fine with one drawback: during processing of libB all the moc and ui files from libA are generated again. In the build directory there is a file src/libA/libA_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp which summarizes all moc files. But src/libB/libB_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp has the content of the file from libA plus the additional moc files from libB.
Similar behaviour with ui files, they are generated a second time during processing of libB.
How can I fix this?

Smells like when you have modified your project, you have used PUBLIC keyword for adding .cpp files to the libA in target_sources call. Your original CMakeLists.txt correctly uses PRIVATE keyword for these files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653516/cmake-building-files-twice-when-using-target-sources-on-common-library.

Oh, of course I have used PRIVATE for cpp files. Just didn't want to pollute the question. So for completeness, this is the content of libA/src/CMakeLists.txt:
target_sources(libA PRIVATE file1.cpp)

The link in the first comment solved the problem. When I add .cpp AND .h files with the PRIVATE keyword to target_sources its working like expected.

Oh, I didn't expect that PUBLIC header files could be a problem. But according to documentation of AUTOUIC and AUTOMOC properties, their generators actually takes into account headers attached to a target via target_sources mechanism. Feel free to answer your question.

The solution was much simpler than I expected: I only had to add ALL source and header files using the PRIVATE keyword of target_sources. Seems that using the PUBLIC keyword populates the INTERFACE_SOURCES property of a target which then delivers the sources to dependent targets as well https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.30/command/target_sources.html
Thanks to @Tsyvarev for giving the right hint!
